# Hiding UITableView searchBar leaves a blank space

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UIViewController with a standard UITableView and Search bar with Search delegate added.  The view has a segmented control in the navigation bar, when the user changes the segmented control I would like to hide the searchBar.

The code I am using is:

```
- (void)segChange {
    if ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setHidden:YES];

        // This does not work:
        [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO]; 

    }
    else {
        [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setHidden:NO];
    }


}
```

The code hides the searchBar fine, but it also leaves a nasty white space at the top of the table view.... any ideas on how to get rid of it???

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code solved the problem:

```
- (void)segChange {
    if ([segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        [self.myTableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
    }
    else {
        [self.myTableView setTableHeaderView:[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar]];
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thanks...worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hiding the segmented control try setting its frame to `CGRectZero`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The segmented controller is in the navigation bar, I am attempting to hide the search bar. I tried setting the searchBar to CGRectZero, but this did not work either.